# Struggling with iterating through a list

Tags: c++, list

```
...
// ConsoleApplication2.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>



void squareVector(std::vector<int>&array1) 
{
    std::list<int> listint;
    for (int j = 0; j < array1.size();++j) 
    {
        listint.push_back(array1[j]);
    }
    std::list<int>::iterator it;
    it = listint.begin();
    int val;

    for (std::list<int>::iterator i = listint.begin(); i != listint.end(); ++i) 
    {
    val = *i * *i;
    listint.insert(it, val);
    ++it;
    }
    for (std::list<int>::iterator i = listint.begin(); i != listint.end(); ++i) 
    {
        std::cout << *i << ", ";    
    }
}

int main()
{
     std::vector<int>intlist ({ 1,3,2,5 });
    squareVector(intlist);
}
```

...

My aim is to take the numbers 1,3,2 & 5 put them in a list, then square each number and place in the list after it, I manage to get them squared and put in the list but for some reason there going in back to front.
i.e the output should be 1,1,3,9,2,4,5,25, but what I'm getting is 1,1,9,3,4,2,25,5.

I have tried adding another increment to the iterator but get an error 'cannot increment end list iterator' on run time.

Edit, thanks everyone for your comments, much appreciated, obviously I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: You don't need a separate iterator for the [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert) call, you can use `i` itself. And please read the linked [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert) reference, it explains exactly what happens (if you didn't guess it already).

Answer (score 0):

From [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert) documentation, the insert function

> inserts value before pos

So when you do this `listint.insert(it, val);` you insert `val` before the position of your iterator `it`. Thus 1,3,2,5 becomes 1²,1,3²,3,2²,2,5²,5 = 1,1,9,3,4,2,25,5.

If you increment the operator you will need to make sure you are not trying to access `listint.end()` since, per the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/end) ,

> std::list::end
>
> Returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the container.
>
> This element acts as a placeholder; **attempting to access it results in undefined behavior.**

As other have pointed out, if you want to just get the square of the original numbers you don't need to insert new values, you can just modify the value in your iterator.

Answer (score 0):

just use a vector/list of std::pair to store the results. pair.first holds your base value, pair.second the result. So you don't need to modify the item count while iterating.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I did consider vectors but the challenge is which is more efficient, and consider that this could be a list of a million numbers, where a list would be more efficient for insertion than a vector?

Comment: it depends... i wanted to avoid modifying the item count while iterating, that's why i suggested using a pair to store base and result value. Works both with vector and list

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to insert an element in the list again. Just take the variable as a reference and modify it. Well, the problem with your code is in insert function.

> Insert function inserts before the given position. Like if you give 4th position it will insert before 4th position.
>
> Read this extract from cpp reference
>   1. pos  -   iterator before which the content will be inserted. pos may be the end() iterator.

So when your execute, you insert before the position of your iterator is pointing. Thus 1,3,2,5 becomes 1²,1,3²,3,2²,2,5²,5 (before 1, then before 3, and so on)

Won't it be better if you leave everything on the compiler? For that use the range-based loop. See below.

```
void squareVector(std::vector<int>&array1)
{
    std::list<int> listint;
    for (int j = 0; j < array1.size();++j)
    {
        listint.push_back(array1[j]);
    }
    std::list<int>::iterator it;
    it = listint.begin();
    int val;

    for(auto &i : listint) // declare i as reference not as plain i.
        i = i*i;
    for (std::list<int>::iterator i = listint.begin(); i != listint.end(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << *i << ", ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a separate iterator and incrementing it separately, you can use `i` itself inside the loop.

```
for (std::list<int>::iterator i = listint.begin(); i != listint.end(); ++i) 
{
    val = *i * *i;
    i=listint.insert(std::next(i), val); // i points to the inserted element

}
```

`std::next` returns the iterator of successor element. `i` needs to be updated after insertion so that it won't get invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need to use the insert method.
but as you can see in the documentation [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-insert-function-in-c-stl/), it inserts in the position you give it in first parameter, pushing everything one element further back.

I'd recommend a simple approach:

```
for (int j = 0; j < array1.size(); ++j)
{
    listint.push_back(array1[j]);
    listint.push_back(array1[j] * array1[j]);
}
```